# Transit visa for Paris or Amsterdam

Tags: visas, schengen, transit, afghan-citizens

I have a passport from Afghanistan with a Canadian visa in it. Do I need a transit visa in Paris or Amsterdam?

Comment: Welcome to Travel Stack Exchange Please explain your situation, failing which this question is bound to get closed.  Add information regarding your travel and which airport you would be in transit and time interval etc.

Comment: I am also going to guess that you are trying to plan your flight to Canada from Afghanistan. Note that the UK has an [exemption from the airside transit visa requirement](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/afghanistan/transit/no) for people with a valid Canadian visa.

Answer (score 1):

Both Paris and Amsterdam are in the Schengen zone, and so your question is answered in Regulation (EC) No 810/2009 of the European Parliament and of the Council of 13 July 2009.

Article 3 states in part...

> Nationals of the third countries listed in Annex IV shall be required
>   to hold an airport transit visa when passing through the international
>   transit areas of airports situated on the territory of the Member
>   States.

Afghanistan is listed in Annex IV

Paragraph 5 lists the exemptions.  It says in part...

> The following categories of persons shall be exempt from the
>   requirement to hold an airport transit visa provided for in paragraphs
>   1 and 2:
>
> (b) third-country nationals holding the valid residence permits listed
>   in Annex V issued by Andorra, Canada, Japan, San Marino or the United
>   States of America guaranteeing the holder’s unconditional readmission;

And Annex V says for Canada...

> CANADA: — Permanent resident card (plastic card).

If you do not meet these requirements, you will need to apply in advance for a "Schengen Airport Transit Visa"

Source http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=celex:32009R0810

Comment: (+1) Point (c) is relevant as well, a regular Canadian visa is also sufficient.

Comment: Criminey, that was an awfully fast lookup and ferreting out of part (c)!